# ADAL JS Angular- WebAPI add a new role claim to the token

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, adal

I have created angular SPA with WEBAPI backend using ADAL JS authentication.As there are no roles in AD, I need to manually add the role claims in order to give users access to different API controllers.

The roles are stored in a database. I am expecting to inject the extra claim through a call to webapi after authentication with AD. 
The webapi Code might look like this.

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user")); 
var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props); 
var accessToken = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
```

Is it possible to replace the ADAL IDtoken with this new token?

Is this a viable solution or is there any other better way to handle this?

As the initial token is  generated by AzureAD, is it possible to edit the token to add the new claim? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding the claim? Do you receive an error message? It seems reasonable that you *should* be able to add the claim, but without at least some idea of what your current code looks like, it's difficult to provide you with a working answer.

Comment: @Claies 

I have used this sample code. 

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-AngularJS-DotNet/

I see that ADAL has stored the token as idtoken. I am trying to see if it is possible to edit this token in anyway to add a role claim.

Comment: you really still haven't clarified your question.  You are using ADAL to authenticate, you don't have any roles in AD, so you want to modify the token to add the roles by hand.  But, where are the roles stored for each user if not in AD? and since you don't control the authorization pipeline here, where would you expect to inject the extra information?

Comment: The roles are stored in a database. 

I am expecting to inject the extra claim through a call to webapi after authentication with AD. 

webapi Code might look like this. 

identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));
 var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
 var accessToken = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);

Is it possible to replace the ADAL ID token with this new token

Is this a viable solution or is there any other better way to handle this.

Comment: if you are going to add more context to your question, you should edit the question and add the extra information / code, code in comments is not formatted and can be unreadable.  Aside from that, I don't think that what you want to do is possible without implementing your own `/Token` endpoint and implementing your own pipeline.

Comment: I have a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580141/angularjs-adal-and-additional-claims-or-properties-for-authorization?noredirect=1#comment78119929_45580141). Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Graph api is supporting the group claims. See here: http://justazure.com/azure-active-directory-part-4-group-claims/

If you look at the examples on that page, users are assigned to groups and your app can check the group in the claims. In current version of the portal, you need to get the app manifest and modify it.